# InfluxQL: How to Return Boolean if value(x) above or below (y) value?

Tags: sql, grafana, influxdb, influxql

I have a measurement value(x) that varies between 0 and 500. I would like to use a query to return 1 (Boolean) if this value(x) is below a set value(y) for example 200 and 0 if it is above. I need to do this for a discrete visualization I want to use.

In SQL Server I would use a case expression like

```
case when col_x < 200 then 1  else  0 end
from <tablename> where <some condition>.
```

But since Influx has no case expression, I have to use a calculation. In question [52533046][1] it is suggested to use something like

```
 FLOOR(1/(value x/80))
```

This wont work for example if cpu field is 5. That equation returns 16 so no use as a boolean.